# Change Primary Color in Strapi?

Tags: css, strapi

I would like to change the primary color of Strapi.
I have already tried a few things, for example I was already in the Node_Modules under strapi-admin and looked at all the files there. Unfortunately without success.

I also looked at the following documentation of Strapi:
https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/guides/custom-admin.html#introduction

But somehow nothing helps, maybe someone of you knows better there.

My Strapi runs on a Docker container and I use the "v3.5.1 Community Edtion" of Strapi.

Comment: It looks like "primary" is coming from `@buffetjs/core` but i couldn't find a way to change or override it in the project either. Removing "primary" and replacing it with a project color like "pale" breaks the app in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors can be found in `node_modules\strapi-admin\admin\src\themes\colors.js`.

Copy them to `admin\src\themes\colors.js` to make your changes. Note that Strapi uses variables for setting the colors so you'll have to find the specific files and update accordingly.

For example: Changing the menu link color would be done in `admin\src\components\LeftMenu\LeftMenuLink\A.js`

```
 &.linkActive {
  color: white !important;
  border-left: 0.3rem solid ${props => props.theme.main.colors.mediumBlue};
}
```

Note the prop. That's how Strapi typical set the colors.

**EDIT**

The primary color can be updated via the Strapi object found in this same file.

```
  strapi: {
   'gray-light': '#eff3f6',
   gray: '#535f76',
   'blue-darker': '#18202e',
   'blue-dark': '#151c2e',
    blue: '#0097f7',
  },
```

Comment: I couldn't find any solution for changing the button color in strapi adminpanel. Everything else can be customized, but buttons

Comment: This color vars are the wrong. Strapi dont have a primary color var! I found a way to change all colors of strapi, but is isnt even worth. Min work time 8 hours.

Comment: @DenisJurkovsek what way is this? mind sharing it?

Answer (score 5):

**ATTENTION:**

All the other answers here are for versions of Strapi **BELOW 4.x.**

The Strapi 4.x documentation is still being worked on, but Strapi 4.x makes customizing *anything* in the admin tool super easy! Check it out...

Just rename `src/admin/app.example.js` to `src/admin/app.js`, or just use my example below. I tried to fill in things you may find useful. Note you can change colors for the dark theme by using the same pattern, just swap out "light" with "dark".

Note: You can replace the favicon and logo as well, just place the files in `src/admin/extensions`.

Note: Remember to run `strapi build` to rebuild the strapi admin panel for your changes to take effect! These changes will not auto-reload.

For a complete list of colors you can change, see https://github.com/strapi/design-system/blob/main/packages/strapi-design-system/src/themes/lightTheme/light-colors.ts

```
import favicon from './extensions/favicon.png'
import logo from './extensions/logo.png'

const config = {
  locales: [
    // 'ar',
    // 'fr',
    // 'cs',
    // 'de',
    // 'dk',
    // 'es',
    // 'he',
    // 'id',
    // 'it',
    // 'ja',
    // 'ko',
    // 'ms',
    // 'nl',
    // 'no',
    // 'pl',
    // 'pt-BR',
    // 'pt',
    // 'ru',
    // 'sk',
    // 'sv',
    // 'th',
    // 'tr',
    // 'uk',
    // 'vi',
    // 'zh-Hans',
    // 'zh',
  ],
  translations: {
    en: {
      'app.components.LeftMenu.navbrand.title': 'What Strapi calls itself (to the right of the logo_'
    }
  },
  menu: {
    logo
  },
  head: {
    favicon
  },
  theme: {
    light: {
      colors: {
        primary100: '#c9ffeb',
        primary200: '#5effc3',
        primary500: '#00f298',
        buttonPrimary500: '#fff298',
        primary600: '#00bd77',
        buttonPrimary600: '#ffbd77',
        primary700: '#008755',
      }
    }
  }
}

const bootstrap = (app) => {
  console.log(app)
}

export default {
  config,
  bootstrap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to complete this... however the result is a little hacky.

Override app.js by copying `nodemodules/strapu-admin/admin/src/app.js` into `admin/src`

Update the copied app.js to include a custom override CSS file, mine looks like so:

```
// Third party css library needed
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js";

// Custom CSS overrides (this is the new override file)
import "../../admin/src/themes/bootstrap-overrides.css";
```

Then simply create a new css file in the location above and override the html attributes as required. E.g.

```
button[color="primary"] {
  background-color: #FC345C !important;
  border-color: #FC345C !important;
}
```

This solution will obviously require you to keep an eye on app.js when upgrading Strapi, however it was the only solution I could find.

Answer (score 0):

@JJ Setsta 's advice is great. As he himself says however, you need to watch out for the changes of the `app.js` file. By adjusting his approach and importing the `overrides.css` and putting it in a file that strapi itself expects to be overwritten by the shadow folder structure (https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#tutorial-videos) ie. `admin/src/config.js` we get the desired outcome without a need to worry about updates.

Example:

admin/src/config.js

```js
export const LOGIN_LOGO = null;
export const SHOW_TUTORIALS = true;
export const SETTINGS_BASE_URL = '/settings';
export const STRAPI_UPDATE_NOTIF = true;

import "./themes/override.css";
```

admin/src/themes/override.css

```css
button[color="primary"] {
  background-color: #FC345C !important;
  border-color: #FC345C !important;
}
```