# How to customize Strapi 4.x Admin Panel default config?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, strapi

I'm tring to edit some default configurations in the Admin Panel of **Strapi 4.x** like primary color and default logo of Strapi but I've no results.

I started a new project using `yarn create strapi-app my-project --quickstart` and followed the Strapi documentation about the "[Admin panel customization](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/admin-panel-customization)".

So I renamed `src/admin/app.example.js` to `src/admin/app.js` and added my logo in the new folder `src/admin/extensions`. After this I've used `strapi build` in the progect folder and than `strapi develop` without having errors in the console. In the admin panel I don't see any changes.

I also tried clearing the browser cache and using the `yarn develop --watch-admin` but it's the same, nothing happened.

I've found also this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67029919/change-primary-color-in-strapi/75295440#75295440) but it din't work.

Strapi Version: 4.15.4
Operating System: MacOs
Database: SQLite
Node Version: v18.18.2
NPM Version: 9.8.1
Yarn Version: 1.22.17

Here is my code (copied from the documentation):

```
import AuthLogo from "./extensions/icon.png";
import MenuLogo from "./extensions/icon.png";
import favicon from "./extensions/icon.png";

export default {
  config: {
    // Replace the Strapi logo in auth (login) views
    auth: {
      logo: AuthLogo,
    },
    // Replace the favicon
    head: {
      favicon: favicon,
    },
    // Add a new locale, other than 'en'
    locales: ["fr", "de"],
    // Replace the Strapi logo in the main navigation
    menu: {
      logo: MenuLogo,
    },
    // Override or extend the theme
    theme: {
      // overwrite light theme properties
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary100: "#f6ecfc",
          primary200: "#e0c1f4",
          primary500: "#ac73e6",
          primary600: "#9736e8",
          primary700: "#8312d1",
          danger700: "#b72b1a",
        },
      },

      // overwrite dark theme properties
      dark: {
        // ...
      },
    },
    // Extend the translations
    translations: {
      fr: {
        "Auth.form.email.label": "test",
        Users: "Utilisateurs",
        City: "CITY (FRENCH)",
        // Customize the label of the Content Manager table.
        Id: "ID french",
      },
    },
    // Disable video tutorials
    tutorials: false,
    // Disable notifications about new Strapi releases
    notifications: { releases: false },
  },

  bootstrap() {},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because of using wrong Strapi version. This issue started from Strapi version v4.15.1 and is still valid in v4.15.4, however it should be fixed in v4.15.5. You can find more information in these Github issues:

- [try to add admin interface languages not working on v14.15.4](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/18786)
- [v4.15.4: Unable to add locales in the admin panel](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/18822)